# Can i install android wear on any smartwatch?

Tags: rom

I just got this smartwatch that is a copy of samsung wear and my question is if i can just format it and install normal android wear.

problem is i dont have any documentation on it and i can barely find any information about the model online.

Answer (score 1):

No. An OEM needs to customize android wear to suit its devices. No one is likely to make such a great effort for a cloned smartwatch so basically, you have to live with what you have...